# How to get a title bar

Tags: text, title

I would like to be able to add picture that always shows at the top part of the screen. I want a bar that stays at the top of it all the time. I do not know how to do it but I believe YouTube has something like it. Except I want it without the content on the side because that is a little annoying.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: you are writting a website , a webapp, a java c / c++ /python/... program ... give more information about your global purpose

Comment: http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/

Comment: Thanks Paul Collingwood

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you have to use absolute positioning. This requires you to use CSS with your HTML (if you are talking about web design).

Here is the CSS

```
img {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

`<img src="YOURIMAGE.jpg" height="100" width="100">`

Not to be disrespectful, but it seems as though you are not familiar with web design. I would recommend looking at W3 schools and try to grasp some of the concepts there before you continue.

Comment: I mean it would stay up at the top even if you scrolled down

Comment: and I use W3 schools all the time

Comment: In that case, used `position: fixed` instead of absolute.